# different utf8 encoding outputs between Python and Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, utf-8, hmac, bytestring

I'm trying to encode a has which is computed by hmac sha256 in Haskell and sometimes my function has different output when compared to it's Python counterpart.

This is the python funciton:

```py
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import time

def strToSign(time, method, endpoint, body):
    return time + method + endpoint + body

str_to_sign2 = strToSign('1','GET','/api/v1/position?symbol=XBTUSDM','')

signature2 = base64.b64encode(
    hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign2.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

And this is the Haskell function:

```hs
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8      as BC
import qualified Data.Text                  as T
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64.URL as U
import           Data.Text.Encoding         (encodeUtf8)
import qualified Crypto.Hash.SHA256         as H

apiSignTest :: BC.ByteString -> BC.ByteString -> BC.ByteString -> BC.ByteString -> IO BC.ByteString
apiSignTest time method endpoint body = do
  let timeStamp = time
  let secret = mconcat [timeStamp,method,endpoint,body]
  let hash = H.hmac (BC.pack C.apiSecretFuture) secret
  return $ (encodeUtf8 . U.encodeBase64) hash
```

some examples where the encoded outputs are different

```py
Haskell : b'KbCFw8OYGeGB433L93vQvbsnzSXxG88r_-HR5AGDJmo='
Python : "KbCFw8OYGeGB433L93vQvbsnzSXxG88r/+HR5AGDJmo=" 

Python : b'dwSmCd75wZToIDt6I0Ik/sX8Vxk4W+RA0Sv1TO+x4WI='
Haskell : "dwSmCd75wZToIDt6I0Ik_sX8Vxk4W-RA0Sv1TO-x4WI="

Python : b'X8SE3ohju6VAu2Dt5nGIQP40+KU9RrhXORAUOdL7rJg='
Haskell : "X8SE3ohju6VAu2Dt5nGIQP40-KU9RrhXORAUOdL7rJg="
```

Comment: Could you add some example where you have different UTF-8. Check the bytes before the use of utf-8. It may be possible that one language normalize Unicode strings (after reading from a file).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Of course.

Comment: There's actually two different base64-es. You seem to be using [Base64Url](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-0.4.2.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64-URL.html#v:encodeBase64) instead of [Base64](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-0.4.2.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64.html#v:encodeBase64).

Comment: What are `C` and `U` in your Haskell code? I think you may have accidentally trimmed a couple relevant imports.

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Data.ByteString.Base64.URL.encodeBase64`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-0.4.2.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64-URL.html#v:encodeBase64) is specifically using the [base64url](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) encoding rather than vanilla base64. The purpose, as the name suggests, is that these encodings can be directly embedded in URLs, which the vanilla version cannot because `/` and `+` have special meanings in URLs.

To get the same behaviour as Python's `b64encode`, use [`Data.ByteString.Base64.encodeBase64`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base64-0.4.2.4/docs/Data-ByteString-Base64.html#v:encodeBase64) instead. Or, the other way around, in Python you can use [`urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode).

Comment: I [raised this as an issue](https://github.com/emilypi/base64/issues/44) for the base64 library.